# What does this error mean: GET http://localhost:30000/....woff2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, font-awesome

I'm trying to get font-awesome fonts working with a react / bootstrap application using webpack. And I'm getting the following error (along with the same for all of the font awesome fonts:

```
GET http://localhost:30000/db812d8a70a4e88e888744c1c9a27e89.woff2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My webpack.config file is as follows:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: "http://localhost:30000/",
  },

  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: "style!css!less",
  },
  {
    test: /\.(css)$/,
    loader: 'style!css'
  },
  { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
  { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
...
```

What's wrong.

Comment: Change `publicPath` to `/` and check that `db812d8a70a4e88e888744c1c9a27e89.woff2` is exists in `dist` folder.

Comment: Changing the publicPath and restarting it fixed it.  Thank you.